# Float json value

Tags: php, json

I got the result set from table in PHP. I have few values as float in this.

In json format it is returning  float value in string "12.0", If I am using json_numeric its only returning 12. What is the best way to handle this.

Comment: That looks right since obviously 12=12.0. Did you try with a value such as "12.123"?

Comment: What do you mean by "to handle this"? What exactly is the issue you are experiencing?